# SQLite Python Query not working when using tkinter with no error messages

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am learning python for my A level and have come across a problem in my project, any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

I have a series of tkinter pages that are designed to be linked by one central page. The search, delete and update functions successfully run SQL queries on their own but lose their functionality when called from the main page, I am getting no visible error messages. I am running SQLite 3.11.2 and Python 3.7.3

The main page calls the attendance page like this (triggered using a button):

```
 def ap():
            AttendancePage.Attendance(Tk())
```

The actual attendance page is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import NEA_SQL_IIII

class Attendance:

    def __init__ (self,root):
        self.root =root
        self.root.title("ODIN Attendance Page")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.config(bg="ghost white")
#These are all the entry widgets, where the values will be added
        Absent = BooleanVar()
        AbsenceNote = BooleanVar()
        TotalAbsences = IntVar()
        StudentName = StringVar()
        StudentID = StringVar()
        should_auto = BooleanVar()

        #function
        #This is the section that will give the buttons their functionality
        def Clear():
            self.entStudentID.delete(0,END)
            self.entStudentName.delete(0,END)
            self.chkAbsent.deselect()
            self.chkAbsenceNote.deselect()
            self.entTotalAbsences.delete(0,END)


        def Exit():
            Exit = tk.messagebox.askyesno("ODIN","Do you wish to exit?")
            if Exit > 0:
                root.destroy()
                return

        def searchDatabase():
            attendanceList.delete(0,END)
            for row in NEA_SQL_IIII.searchA(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get()):
                attendanceList.insert(END,row,str(""))


        def viewData():
            attendanceList.delete(0,END)
            for row in NEA_SQL_IIII.displayA():
                attendanceList.insert(END,row,str(""))

        def deleteData():
            if(len(StudentName.get())!=0):
               NEA_SQL_IIII.DeleteDataA(sd[0])
               Clear()
               viewData()

        def AttendRec(event):
            global sd
            searchAttend = attendanceList.curselection()[0]
            sd = attendanceList.get(searchAttend)

            self.entStudentID.delete(0,END)
            self.entStudentID.insert(END,sd[0])
            self.entStudentName.delete(0,END)
            self.entStudentName.insert(END,sd[1])
            self.chkAbsent.deselect()
            self.chkAbsent.select()
            self.chkAbsenceNote.deselect()
            self.chkAbsenceNote.select()
            self.entTotalAbsences.delete(0,END)
            self.entTotalAbsences.insert(END,sd[4])

        def Update():
            if(len(StudentID.get())!=0):
                NEA_SQL_IIII.DeleteDataA(sd[0])
            if(len(StudentID.get())!=0):
                NEA_SQL_IIII.addStudentA(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get(),Absent.get(),AbsenceNote.get(),TotalAbsences.get())
                attendanceList.delete(0,END)
                attendanceList.insert(END,(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get(),Absent.get(),AbsenceNote.get(),TotalAbsences.get()))


        #Frames
        #These will define all the different frames

        MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg="Ghost White")
        MainFrame.grid()

        TitFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, padx=54, pady=8, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE)
        TitFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.lblTit = Label(TitFrame ,font=('ariel', 47,'bold'),text="ODIN Attendance Page",bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblTit.grid()

        ButtonFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, width=1350, height=70, padx=18, pady=10, bg="blue2", relief = RIDGE)
        ButtonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        DataFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=1, width=1300, height=400, padx=20, pady=20, bg="ghost white", relief = RIDGE)
        DataFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        #DataFrameTOP = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=1000, height=300, padx=20, pady=4, relief = RIDGE,  bg="Ghost White", font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Info\n")
        #DataFrameTOP.pack(side=TOP)

        DataFrameLEFT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=200, padx=20,pady=3, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE, font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Info\n")
        DataFrameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT)

        DataFrameRIGHT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=200, padx=31,pady=3, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE, font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Details\n")
        DataFrameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT)

#Label and Entry Widget
#These are the widgets that will allow for labels onto the entry sections


        self.lblStudentID = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Student ID", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblStudentID.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entStudentID = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=StudentID,  width=39)
        self.entStudentID.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lblStudentName = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Student Name", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblStudentName.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entStudentName = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=StudentName,  width=39)
        self.entStudentName.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lblAbsent = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Absent?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblAbsent.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.chkAbsent = Checkbutton(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=Absent, variable = should_auto, onvalue = True, offvalue = False, width=39)
        self.chkAbsent.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lblAbsenceNote = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Absence Note?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblAbsenceNote.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.chkAbsenceNote = Checkbutton(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=AbsenceNote,  width=39, onvalue = True, offvalue = False)
        self.chkAbsenceNote.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.lblTotalAbsences = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Total Absences?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
        self.lblTotalAbsences.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entTotalAbsences = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=TotalAbsences,  width=39)
        self.entTotalAbsences.grid(row=4, column=1)



        #scrollbar

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(DataFrameRIGHT)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = 'ns')

        attendanceList = Listbox(DataFrameRIGHT, width=41, height=16, font=('ariel',12,'bold'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        attendanceList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',AttendRec)
        attendanceList.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=8)
        scrollbar.config(command = attendanceList.yview)

#button
        #self.btnAddDate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Add New', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=addData)
        #self.btnAddDate.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnDisplay = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Display', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=viewData)
        self.btnDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnClear = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Clear', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=Clear)
        self.btnClear.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.btnDelete = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Delete', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = deleteData)
        self.btnDelete.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.btnSearch = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Search', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = searchDatabase)
        self.btnSearch.grid(row=0, column=3)

        #self.btnUpdate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Update', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = updateData)
        #self.btnUpdate.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.btnUpdate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Update', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = Update)
        self.btnUpdate.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.btnQuit = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Quit', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=Exit)
        self.btnQuit.grid(row=0, column=5)


if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    application = Attendance(root)
    root.mainloop()'''
```

The SQL code that is being called is:

```
def Attendance():
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST Attendance (Absent BOOLEAN, AbsenceNote BOOLEAN, TotalAbsences INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY StudentName REFERENCES StudentRecord(StudentName),FOREIGN KEY StudentID REFERENCES StudentRecord(StudentID), PRIMARY KEY(StudentID)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def displayA():
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Attendance")
    rows =cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def DeleteDataA(StudentID):
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM Attendance WHERE StudentID=?", (StudentID,))
    con.commit()
    return con, cur
    con.close()

def searchA(StudentName="", StudentID=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db", isolation_level=None)
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE StudentName=? OR StudentID=?", (StudentName,StudentID,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def UpdateDataA(StudentID="", StudentName="", Behaviour="", Achievement="", Detention="", ProgressLevel=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("StudentRecord.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE StudentRecord SET StudentName=?, Behaviour=?, Achievement=?, Detention=?, ProgressLevel=? WHERE StudentID=? ", (StudentID,StudentName,Behaviour,Achievement,Detention,ProgressLevel))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Are you aware that `StudentID` is an object, not a string?

Comment: I defined it as a string elsewhere, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I see. Have you verified it is a string at the point where the error occurs, and that it is the value you expect?

Comment: I'm new to this, can you please tell me how you know that it is an object and not a string? As I mentioned no error messages are displayed.

Comment: I saw this: `StudentID = StringVar()`. `StringVar` is a class, so `StringVar()` returns an object. I didn't see that you also have a variable named `StudentID`. If you `print(StudentID)` and/or `print(type(StudentID)` immediately before calling `cur.execute`  you can see exactly what is being used in the sql statement.